# Cant insert any data when hierarchial partition key is involved

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can't seem to insert any data when there is a hierarchial  partition key. I keep getting the "(Partition key provided either doesn't correspond to definition in the collection or doesn't match partition key field values specified in the document." error but it doesn't make sense as I am providing the right key and document has those values

'key' variable is a string variable containing a guid:

[image]

```
                dynamic document = new 
                {
                    Id = key,
                    ObjectName = "PlayerInfo",
                    PlayerID = key,
                    PlayerInfo = "foobarbaz"
                    // other document properties
                };

                string partitionKeyValue = $"/{document.ObjectName}/{document.PlayerID}";

                ItemResponse<dynamic> resp = await container.CreateItemAsync(document, new PartitionKey(partitionKeyValue));
```

Comment: What is the partition key path? What is a sample value you're using in your `partitionKeyValue` ? Please edit accordingly. Right now, it looks like you're providing the `path to the partition key` as your `partitionKeyValue`

Comment: Ah - once I embedded your image properly, it's now much clearer: you're using a hierarchical partition key with `/ObjectName` and `/PlayerID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a hierarchical partition key, you need to specify all the parts of the partition key. In your case, maybe construct your partition key with something like this:

```cs
var partitionKey = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
   .Add("PlayerInfo")
   .Add("key")
   .Build();
ItemResponse<dynamic> resp = await container.CreateItemAsync(document, partitionKey);
```

You can compare using `PartitionKeyBuilder().Build()` output to the partition key value you constructed, to see what the differences are...

Comment: THANK you, the PartitionKeyBuilder worked perfectly. It looks like its generating a JSON doc like this: "{["PlayerInfo","GUIDVALUE"]}" like it's creating an array of 2 strings in a json object. Everything online said to use slashes, not a json array.

Comment: @user3010678 The official documentation for the Hierarchical Partition Key feature contains the PartitionKeyBuilder examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep#manually-specify-the-path.